# Unable To Mount Folder In DataBrick

Tags: databricks, mount

I am trying to run the code to mount the folder in Azure Blob Storage. I tried with another blob storage account with enabled soft delete, and it still works. But when I create another blob storage account and try to mount it to that blob folder, it does not work because my blob has been activated with the soft delete feature. Any setting is needed to complete this task, but not disable the soft delete setting in blob storage data protection. Please let me know if you guys have the solution. Many thanks.

Pic1: blob storage (dlsbdpdwhtest) that I can mount but did not disable the soft delete [dlsbdpdwhtest account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fengt.png)

setting for this account
[dlsbdpdwhtest data protection setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeBmd.png)

Pic2: blob storage (dlsbdpdwhdev) that I cannot mount [dlsbdpdwhdev account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DHpb.png)

setting for this account
[dlsbdpdwhdev data protection setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Eig.png)

Any setting that I need to check before running the code for mounting the folder in the blob storage setting

Here is the code for mounting

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": bdp_datalake_access_application_id,
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": bdp_datalake_access_secret_value ,
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": bdp_datalake_endpoint }
mount_source = f"abfss://bdp-dwh@dlsbdpdwhdev.dfs.core.windows.net/"
mount_folder = "/mnt/bdp-dwh"
print(mount_source)
dbutils.fs.mount(source = mount_source,mount_point = mount_folder,extra_configs = configs)
```

Comment: Hi there, please share codes , error logs in a plain text format, as images can't be reproduced!

Comment: Here is the error log:
< org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Operation failed: "This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.", 409, HEAD, https://dlsbdpdwhdev.dfs.core.windows.net/bdp-dwh/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90 >

Answer (score 0):

In your Storage account, make sure the Blob Soft Delete option is Disabled. If it's enabled, follow the next step to learn how to disable it.

[image]

For details review this page

https://ganeshchandrasekaran.com/azure-databricks-configure-your-storage-container-to-load-and-write-data-to-azure-object-storage-3db8cd506a25